# nwjs migrating from 0.12 to 10.18

Tags: nwjs

I am facing a problem upgrading from nw.js version 0.12 to 0.18.

I have a situation while I start from the index.html file from the .nw package. From the file, I navigate to my online version of the app by navigating to the link mytestapp.com/page1online.html. From the Online version of the page located at mytestapp.com/page1online.html, I want to navigate back to an HTML page in the .nw package called page1offline.html. The page1offline.html is located in the root of the .nw package.

In nw.js version 0.12, I used the app:// protocol to navigate to any page located inside the .nw package. Now, since it has been deprecated and instead chrome-extension:// was introduced this navigation is broken.

I tried the using chrome-extension:// instead to the app:// but it did not work. Tried the file:// option but that too did not yield the desired result. Also tried many other options but was disappointed.

Can somebody please help me how to navigate to a static HTML file located inside the .nw package from the live online page opened from the nw.js application.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards & Happy Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to use/navigate/redirect to an HTML resource in an NW package from a hosted HTML page is to have this entry in the package.json file.

"web_accessible_resources": [
       "*.html"
   ]
}

Also, to reference the resource we should use the chrome-extension protocol as
window.location.href = "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/mytestpage.html"

Wasted lot of my time on this. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got the local file path format wrong. It should be like this (3 forward slashes)...

```
file:///C:/abc.png
```

But if the file is inside your NW package then you should be able to access it directly by its name like this... (no need for a path)

```
SomeFrame.src='abc.png';
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But, my situation is a bit different, The HTML resource was not inside the NW package. It was a resource from a LIVE hosted site. From the Live hosted resource I wanted to switch back to an HTML resource hosted inside the .NW. I have a found a solution though.